# Keep track of when player enters/leaves a zone in game

Tags: mysql, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a UI based game where you have a "world map" containing a grid with zones (squares).

The zones are loaded through a json file coming from a database (MySQL) and are presented in a Grid Layout Group. Each zone has a zoneID in the database which is set in a local variable on the zone prefab.

When the player (you) are clicking on a zone, you will get a "Travel to"-button.
When the "Travel to" button is pressed, the idea is to "move" the player to that zone, coloring the image frame of the zone in yellow to highlight where you are. There is no actual player moving around, just UI and Text displaying the information.

My problem(s):

1. What would be a good and simple way to let the system know in which zone you are?
   I'm thinking about a bool or something like (bool playerInZone), but how do I set it to true/false on other zones?
2. How do I reset the color when player leaves a zone and enters another? Currently I have no problem setting the color when pressing the button, but I can't seem to figure out how to reset the previous zone.

I can't seem to wrap my head around this...

I'm not sure if code is needed, I just need tips for how to think in this case.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would help if you showed us what you have created so far, but as a possible solution to 1., how about something like `move(oldZone, newZone)`? That way you know exactly what zones to modify.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit after understanding the question better:**

I think I understand where your confusion comes from. You probably think that game-objects should manifest in the game view/physics in some way, where in fact many game-objects are just invisible units carrying game-logic related code.

I think a good solution would be to keep a manager game object that keeps track on the current location of the player. When you intercept a UI input that moves the player you'll do it through the manager, and the manager will be responsible to remove the highlighting from the current zone and apply it to the new zone.

It's probably a good idea to keep the "zones" as child objects of the said manager. Read about how to find game objects from parent game objects. I'm not sure which object intercepts the mouse click, but assuming that it's the zones themselves, than the manager can subscribe to events on the zones that will fire upon being clicked, or simply refactor to have a single object (perhaps the manager) handle the UI inputs.

Hope this is more helpful. Let me know if you need any clarification.

**Previous comment**

Use a [collider trigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-isTrigger.html).

You can use the [OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) and [OnTriggerExit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerExit.html) to set a bool whenever the player is in the zone. If you want coordination between different triggers and different zones you'll need a manager of some sort to handle this.

Comment: I know about triggers and colliders. But as I mentioned. This game doesn't have any "player" like you normally would since this is a UI based game. There are mostly buttons and icons for everything. So there is no player physically entering a zone.